# UISearchBar no longer editable when the dismiss the modal view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uisearchbar, viewcontroller

I have a `tableView` with some elements and on the top of the view, there is a `UISearchBar`. When the first time, I use the search bar everything works fine. I can write, edit and delete the text inside and the search bar and also filters my `tableView`. 
But the problem arises, when I select one of the item from the tableView(the table view shows a list of campsites) and it opens a new view with the details of the item.
When I come back to the tableView from the detailView, using the following code

```
[[self parentViewController]dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

the `searchBar` is no longer editable. The keyboard doesn't appear and if I touch the searchBar, nothing happens.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: show your code.. check you are doing disabling user interaction anywhere in your code.

Comment: I don't think i disable user interaction... How can I do?

Comment: Thanks, but all your suggestions don't work. For me is a big problem because searching on internet I haven't found any solution. Maybe is a Xcode bug? Because I've tried to resolve the problem by creating the search bar via "code" (not using IB), and I have the same problem.

Comment: Its a problem of layout constraints or autoresizing. I have had a same problem yesterday for my view. I just removed the UIViewAutoResizingFlexible Margins on all sides and unchecked the autoresize subviews option for my view's superview.

Comment: how can i remove the UiViewAutoResizingFlexible Margin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that some other view is overlapping the searchbar.Also check the userInteraction of the searchbar